# Saving best Solution of Random Mutation Hill Climbing algorithm - Java

Tags: java, algorithm

I am trying to save the best solution for my algorithm that prints out a solution for a binary scales problem.
My code **is** saving the best Fitness result (the lowest number) but it's not saving the best Scales solution (the binary code) that should be the Scales solution of the best Fitness.

```
public static ScalesSolution RMHC(ArrayList<Double> weights, int iter) {
if(weights == null || weights.size() == 0 || iter < 1) {        
    return null;                                               
}                                                              

ScalesSolution sol = new ScalesSolution(weights.size());        
ScalesSolution newSol = new ScalesSolution(sol.GetSol());       
double oldSolFitness = sol.ScalesFitness(weights);              
double newSolFitness = 0;                                       

for(int i = 1; i <= iter; i++) {                                
    newSol.SmallChange();                                       
    newSolFitness = newSol.ScalesFitness(weights);              

    if(newSolFitness < oldSolFitness) {                         

        oldSolFitness = newSolFitness;                          

        sol = new ScalesSolution(newSol.GetSol());              

    }                                                           
    else if(newSolFitness > oldSolFitness) {                    
        newSolFitness = oldSolFitness;                          
        sol = new ScalesSolution(newSol.GetSol());              

    }                                                           
    oldSolFitness = newSolFitness;                             


    System.out.println(newSol.GetSol() + "; " + newSolFitness);

}                                                               
return sol;
```

}

In conclusion I want to save the Solution (binary) of the best Fitness found, instead of saving the last Solution found.

If any more info is needed please message me, thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you show us the ScalesSolution object?

Comment: You have the `sol = ...` in both cases. Why? Shouldn't it only contain the solution of maximum fitness?